What is a good material to use in a blood vessel model?
I'm trying to create a training model for neurosurgery that utilizes 3D printed bones and associated vessels. I intend to use a pump to run artifical blood through these vessels. So they need to be elastic and should be possibly damaged/cut by the wrong cutting maneuvers or drill touches. Ideally they should be able to hold a suture. Is there a commercially available item that can be used as such?
I've seen surgical drains and IV tunes that used in this fashion in the literature.

What an interesting question! You are definitely creating a model... unfortunately 'modelling' in the context of this site means 'computer modelling'. See here for an explanation of what this site is about!
Still, a cool question. Maybe you could use some thin-walled surgical  (latex) tubing? I even found some red tubing on amazon!
You might not get the best help you need on this site since we are computer nerds. Moreover, your question may end up being closed by moderators as off topic. I suggest you look for another SE site or maybe try Reddit?
Cheers!

Oops. This post misleaded me I guess... :/ https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348194.      Yes, I remember from my school years, nurses used those as tourniquets. They have a good elasticity. They're just a bit "traction"-y so they'd stick and hold on to stuff... but a good idea nonetheless
